# How can I implement an access control system with session variables?

Tags: php, session

On the login page, I set a session variable with an ID (we are assuming that ID of 1 is always admin). When a user browses to the page that only an admin has access to, `check.php` acts as a middleman that checks to see if a session variable is set and if it is 1, then it will redirect the user to the admin page, and another page if it is not. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";
    session_start();

    #Check to see if session variables are set properly. Only the administrator can have access to this page
    if(!isset($_SESSION) || $_SESSION['id'] != 1) {
        header('Location: restricted.php');
        die();
    } else {
        header('Location: admin.php');
        die();
    }
 ?>
```

When I go to my login page and successfully login with admin credentials, and try the check.php page, it takes me to admin.php. If I don't log in it still takes me to the admin page.

What exactly is my issue with this script?

Comment: Because the `else` will execute if the conditions aren't met. Either change the redirect in the else or create another set of conditions.

Comment: Oh that is true. I didn't realize that. Thank you!

Comment: @JayBlanchard why did you answer as a comment? Doesn't that mean this question stays open and other people will keep looking at it in order to try and answer it?

Comment: Because @geoidesic, the comment seemed sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the else will execute if the conditions aren't met. Either change the redirect in the else or create another set of conditions.

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION) || $_SESSION['id'] != 1) { // CONDITION NOT MET
        header('Location: restricted.php');
        die();
    } else {
        header('Location: admin.php'); // REDIRECT OCCURS
        die();
    }
```